# Name node never leaves safe mode eventhough none of the files are corrupted and jps shows name node twice

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop using (brew install hadoop). For 4 months it was running correctly. i realised that mapred-site.xml was configured to jobtracker So. i changed to yarn and restarted then i found data node is missing . i reinstalled hadoop and found some corrupted files. i deleted that files using fsck. but still the name node will stay in the safe mode. I tried re-installing hadoop 5 times and also i uninstalled brew and installed all fresh again . I am still not able to figure it out.Any help will be appreciated. I have assignments to be completed this week.

jps

```
28723 SecondaryNameNode
33876 Jps
16309 NameNode
28504 NameNode
28856 ResourceManager
61292 JoveScala
32701 DataNode
28958 NodeManager
```

core-site.xml

```
 <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
   <property>
    <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
    <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
   <property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
```

bin/hdfs dfsadmin -report

```
    Safe mode is ON
    Configured Capacity: 120124866560 (111.88 GB)
    Present Capacity: 40319258624 (37.55 GB)
    DFS Remaining: 40319250432 (37.55 GB)
    DFS Used: 8192 (8 KB)
    DFS Used%: 0.00%
    Under replicated blocks: 0
    Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
    Missing blocks: 0
    Missing blocks (with replication factor 1): 26
    -------------------------------------------------
    Live datanodes (1):

    Name: 127.0.0.1:50010 (localhost)
    Hostname: 192.168.0.15
    Decommission Status : Normal
    Configured Capacity: 120124866560 (111.88 GB)
    DFS Used: 8192 (8 KB)
    Non DFS Used: 79805607936 (74.32 GB)
    DFS Remaining: 40319250432 (37.55 GB)
    DFS Used%: 0.00%
    DFS Remaining%: 33.56%
    Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
    Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
    Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
    Cache Used%: 100.00%
    Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
    Xceivers: 1
    Last contact: Fri Jan 13 11:41:49 PST 2017
```

hdfs fsck / | egrep -v '^.+$' | grep -v eplica

```
    Connecting to namenode via            http://localhost:50070/fsckugi=krishnaprasad&path=%2F
    FSCK started by krishnaprasad (auth:SIMPLE) from /127.0.0.1 for    path / at Fri Jan 13 12:07:11 PST 2017
     Status: HEALTHY
     Total size:    0 B
     Total dirs:    1
     Total files:   0
     Total symlinks:        0
     Total blocks (validated):  0
     Corrupt blocks:        0
     Number of data-nodes:      1
     Number of racks:       1
     FSCK ended at Fri Jan 13 12:07:11 PST 2017 in 3 milliseconds
     The filesystem under path '/' is HEALTHY
```

Comment: the `dfsadmin -report` says its missing 26 blocks(which looks like your entire hdfs) and that is the reason the namenode is still in Safemode.

Comment: the      hdfs fsck -list-corruptfileblocks  shows  0 corrupted files

Comment: You do not have any corrupt blocks but missing blocks. This arises when you do not have the actual data blocks but the metadata is present.

Comment: can you please tell me how to resolve this . Thank you . and why is that name node showing twice ?

Comment: i tried formatting namenode many times it didn't worked :(

Comment: `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave` will make your leave the safemode forcefully. But this is not a permanent solution.

Comment: hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave       it won't last even for few seconds

Comment: Did you try deleting the contents of `/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp` and formatting the namenode?

Comment: i keep on deleting tmp file but still it automatically reappears and in http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview  Name  node storage: Failed  even i changed the location of tmp in hdfs-site.xml once but didn't work

Comment: Can you explicitly specify the properties `dfs.namenode.name.dir` and `dfs.datanode.data.dir` to new directories in `hdfs-site.xml` and format the namenode.

Comment: i did but still /usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/hdfs/tmp reappears

Comment: It has to re-appear. `hadoop.tmp.dir` is to be used as the parent directory for all hadoop daemon specific directories which are not explicitly defined.

Comment: Eventhough i stop, stop-dfs.sh and start-dfs.sh i am still able to connect to http://localhost:50070/dfshealth.html#tab-overview

Comment: Can you please tell me how to kill the process . i stopped all the daemons .but still able to access hdfs directory.

Comment: kill -9 `pid_of_process`. I believe a namenode process is still running. Check the output of `jps`.

Comment: now datanode is missing in jps. and name node safe mode is off

Comment: remove the datanode data directory and restart it with `hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode`

Comment: Thank you very much . now it's working fine. Happy Pongal :)